# Moving the server to new location

Tags: ip, colocation

We just moved our dedicated server to a new DC (Colocation). I modified the ifcfg-eth0 with the new IP and gateway but the server is not responding yet. As far as I know adding the new IP in eth0 would be enough to make the server online. Is there anything else to be modified?

Comment: `I modified the ifcfg-eth0 with the new IP and gateway but the server is not responding yet` - What does that mean exactly? Responding how? In what way?

Comment: @joeqwerty It's a CentOS server. That's how we change the main IP of a CentOS server. But the server is still unreachable.

Comment: Unreachable in what way? SSH, HTTP, SMTP, etc.? You really need to give us more detail on how you're trying to access the server and what kind of connectivity to the server you're trying to establish.

Comment: @joeqwerty the server is unreachable at all. No SSH, no http , no ping ...

Comment: Being nitpicky: Changing the IP address wont help unless you also change the default gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you restarted networking services after modifying the network IP and gateway information. A `service network restart` will do this for you.

You'll also want to edit your `/etc/hosts` file.